# What is the perferred way to customize the form variable from a class-based Generic View in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-generic-views

I am currently using `CreateView` for the class `Order`.

Part of the `urls.py` looks like this

```
url(
    r'^orders/create/$',
    CreateView.as_view(
        model = Order,
        template_name = 'doors/orders/create.html'
    ),
    name = 'orders_create'
),
```

If I simply do a `{{ form }}` inside a `oors/orders/create.html`, then it will display all the fields declared in `models.py`.

[image]

What is the best way to customize the look of each field and to even control whether they are even visible or not (some of the fields are optional)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the part of your question concerning which fields of the model should be available in the form, you could create a custom form with `ModelForm`. The options `fields` and `exclude` define which fields are available in the form:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form

You would then tell the `CreateView` to use your custom form by adding `form_class`:

```
url(
    r'^orders/create/$',
    CreateView.as_view(
        model = Order,
        template_name = 'doors/orders/create.html',
        form_class = OrderCreateForm,
    ),
    name = 'orders_create'
),
```

Concerning the second part of your question (how to style the form and its fields), you could use `{{ form.as_p }}`, `{{ form.as_table }}` or put together a completely custom template:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template

Comment: So I'm suppose to create the `OrderCreateForm` inside `models.py`?

Comment: It's good practice to put your custom forms in a module called `forms.py` (at the same level as your `models.py`.

Comment: I was reading the documentation you linked and [their full example put all the form classes right next to the model classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example). So the documentation gave a bad example?

Comment: Mh, good question. Maybe I'll ask it on the Django Mailinglist. Most of the time, I stick to this list of conventions: http://streamhacker.com/2011/01/03/django-application-conventions/